# Retrieving boot time using GetTickCount64

Tags: winapi, systemtime, filetime

I'm trying to extract boot time by getting current time SYSTEMTIME structure, then converting it to FILETIME which I then convert to ULARGE_INTEGER from which I subtract GetTickCount64() and then proceed on converting everything back to SYSTEMTIME.

I'm comparing this function to 'NET STATISTICS WORKSTATION' and for some reason my output is off by several hours, which don't seem to match any timezone differences.

Here's visual studio example code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#define KILOBYTE 1024
#define BUFF KILOBYTE


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ULARGE_INTEGER ticks, ftime;
    SYSTEMTIME current, final;
    FILETIME ft, fout;

    OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;

    char output[BUFF];
    int retval=0;
    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
    ZeroMemory(&final, sizeof(SYSTEMTIME));
    GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO *) &osvi);

    if (osvi.dwBuildNumber >= 6000) ticks.QuadPart = GetTickCount64();
    else ticks.QuadPart = GetTickCount();
    //Convert miliseconds to 100-nanosecond time intervals
    ticks.QuadPart = ticks.QuadPart * 10000;
    //GetLocalTime(&current); -- //doesn't really fix the problem
    GetSystemTime(&current);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&current, &ft);
    printf("INITIAL: Filetime lowdatetime %u, highdatetime %u\r\n", ft.dwLowDateTime, ft.dwHighDateTime);
    ftime.LowPart=ft.dwLowDateTime;
    ftime.HighPart=ft.dwHighDateTime;
    //subtract boot time interval from current time
    ftime.QuadPart = ftime.QuadPart - ticks.QuadPart;
    //Convert ULARGE_INT back to FILETIME
    fout.dwLowDateTime = ftime.LowPart;
    fout.dwHighDateTime = ftime.HighPart;
    printf("FINAL: Filetime lowdatetime %u, highdatetime %u\r\n", fout.dwLowDateTime, fout.dwHighDateTime);
    //Convert FILETIME back to system time
    retval = FileTimeToSystemTime(&fout, &final);
    printf("Return value is %d\r\n", retval);
    printf("Current time %d-%.2d-%.2d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\r\n", current.wYear, current.wMonth, current.wDay,  current.wHour, current.wMinute, current.wSecond);
    printf("Return time %d-%.2d-%.2d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\r\n", final.wYear, final.wMonth, final.wDay,  final.wHour, final.wMinute, final.wSecond);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran it and found that it works correctly when using `GetLocalTime` as opposed to GetSystemTime, which is expressed in UTC.  So it would make sense that GetSystemTime would not necessarily match the "clock" on the PC.

Other than that, though, the issue could possibly be the call to GetVersionEx.  As written, I think it will always return zeros for all values.  You need this line prior to calling it:

```
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof( osvi );
```

Otherwise that dwBuildNumber will be zero and it will call GetTickCount, which is only good for 49 days or so.  On the other hand, if that were the case, I think you would get a result with a much larger difference.

I'm not completely sure that (as written) the check is necessary to choose which tick count function to call.  If GetTickCount64 doesn't exist, the app would not load due to the missing entrypoint (unless perhaps delay loading was used ... I'm not sure in that case). I believe that it would be necessary to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to make the decision dynamically between those two functions and have it work on an older platform.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clear up that point, I intended GetTickCount64 to be run on vista system or later (build number >= 6000) and turn GetTickCount on xp, 2003 etc... But as you explained, I implemented that feature incorrectly, and I need to use LoadLibraryEx. Still, on my system 'net statistics workstation' returns 'Statistics since 18/03/2011 1:40:58 PM' and this code: 'Return time 2011-03-18 18:01:23'

Comment: Could it be because the system is virtualized (KVM guest) that I'm getting this discrepancy?

Comment: @user86294:  I ran it on several machines (vmware images and 3 physical boxes including 32-bit, 64-bit, win7, xp ...).  It worked correctly in all cases.  Did you run it on a machine that you "know" when it was restarted?  I am not really familiar with "net statistics" and whether it is "guaranteed" to show the boot time.

Comment: I don't remember it exactly, but I also check it using event log. In event log reboot timestamps is 2011-03-18 9:40:39 which is considering my time zone (EDT) is pretty close to what 'net statistics workstation' is showing. I guess I'm going to reboot it, try to run the code on a few more machines and get back to you on that.